# Typescript tuple of two booleans being inferred as an array of type boolean

Tags: typescript, tuples, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I tried making a tuple of two booleans to place in my `BehaviorSubject`

```
private someBehaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<[boolean, boolean]> = new BehaviorSubject([false, false]);
```

but I get a compilation error saying:

```
Type 'BehaviorSubject<boolean[]>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<[boolean, boolean]>'
```

How can I create a tuple of two booleans, and initialize the BehaviorSubject properly? It seems to think `[false, false]` is of type `boolean[]` and not a tuple where index 0, and index 1 are required to be booleans.

Typescript version: `2.3.3`

BehaviorSubject from rxjs v`5.0.1`

Comment: * as a matter of taste - in the example you've given - `boolean[]` is a reasonable inferred type. You can/should define your tupples as types/interfaces, imho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tuples are currently a bit tricky to work with in TypeScript. Array literals might be accidentally inferred to an array type rather than a tuple, which is what happened in this case. The compiler has resolved `new BehaviorSubject([false, false])` too eagerly to an object of type `BehaviorSubject<boolean[]>`, without checking the destination variable's type. This is a known concern and many related issues were posted in the issue tracker ([#16391](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16391), [#15656](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15656), and possibly more) and suggestions have been laid to address it ([#10195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10195), [#16656](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16656), ...).

For particular cases where inference fails, you may simply have to resort to casting:

```
private someBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject([false, false] as [boolean, boolean]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update for TypeScript 3.4:

With a new syntax being introduced in TypeScript 3.4, we'll have the option to declare a so-called **"const context"**. This allows us to easily declare a given array as immutable (as in "cannot be changed after declaration") and thus allow the compiler to assume a "narrow" type.

This way we can declare:

```
private someBehaviorSubject = new BehaviourSubject(<const> [false, false])

// notice the <const>, alternatively we could write "[false, false] as const"
```

And infer the correct type `BehaviourSubject<[false, false]>`